# Spring Boot Suggestions Endpoint Optimization

Tags: spring-boot, rest, elasticsearch, optimization

I have a microservice that have Rest endpoint which returns suggested item names. For every character entered in the text field (Min 3 character) this endpoint is invoked.

The endpoint internally calls elastic search which fetches the items based on query string.

When RPM increases with APM monitoring there is a huge spike in the heap consumptions as well.

Any idea how could I optimize this endpoint?